# SMS or PUSH Notifications for "mobile first" orders delivery?

Tags: mobile, push-notification, sms, e-commerce, sms-gateway

a general question about sending realtime messaging from a cloud server
to users with handsets.

I'm creating new ecommerce: ROSPO - Snap Commerce for Local Trades
( enjoy small video introduction: http://www.rosposhop.com )

Now, my problem is to find the BEST way to deliver Online Orders
(submitted by online buyer) to a seller with a cell phone in his hands.

Order delivery must be in REALTIME and with a "delivery receipt"
confirmation requirement (I need to know for sure if order arrived into
the seller mobile phone, so no beloved e-mails, sorry).

**1. Push Notifications**

A native app with some sort of push notification protocol for orders
notifications ?

by example using https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html for
Android, something similar fo IoS, something similar for Microsoft Phone
OS, etc.) ?

**2. SMS**

pros:
- Old plain "delivey receipt" SMS text messages. They always reach
receivers also in area without 3G coverage...
- SMSs do not require any native app. any sort of cellphone is ok.

cons:
sending (and receiving) SMSs is expensive! Let consider text message orders could be many SMS's segments... (an order is usually 160 x N chars), with N = 2-8. And just sending a single SMS, with some gateway providers in Europe cost is between 0.03 to 0.07 EUR.

Any further suggestion ?

BTW, any good experience with SMS gateway providers like: Twillio.com /
Nexmo.com ? I used until now with success Italian Skebby.com, but I
possibly need the CHEAPEST&AFFORDABLE provider that act in worlwide
countries (ROSPO servers will be instantiated in any city all around the
world...)

thanks :-)
giorgio

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any option is really able to provide reliable delivery receipt. SMS is unreliable in various countries, and device Push Notifications can be over-ridden on the local device but still look like they've been sent on your side.

That said SMS is the most general solution to the problem and will cover the most use cases. If you're going to go the Push Notification route though I guess that means you'll have an app on the user's device, in which case the most reliable way would be to have push notifications (or maybe give the user an option to have SMS aswell/instead?) which they then need to acknowledge receipt within the app. That way you're relying on their action to confirm acknowledge it rather than making assumptions based on delivery.

Comment: thanks. SMS WAY: low level speaking: I like SMS with "delivery receipt" mode, allowed by some gateways providers, as nexmo/skebby. I would discern the fact SMS arrive to device, from the fact (application level) the user explictely do some "acknowledge" replying with SMS (no app) or doing some IP feedback (with an app). PUSH NOTIFICATION WAY: my ask is: there isa some push protocol that allow server to know if message (the order) really arrived to device ?

Comment: Push notification way: unfortunately not.

Comment: You confirm my suspect. I will go with old good sms with delivery receipt (maybe "catched" inside an android app)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Now there's [Catapush](http://www.catapush.com): push notifications with sms fallback feature :)

Comment: Yes... I know catapush features; BTW, my question is one year old (when Catapush founders was at Skebby :) ). Now a free solution is use an instant messaging chatbot (e.g. on Telegram).